# URL to add Android Support Library to SDK Manager

Tags: android, macos, android-studio, android-sdk-tools, android-sdk-manager

I accidentally deleted the `Android Support Library` from the `Extras` folder in my SDK Manager. To add this back, I thought finding the library URL (.xml) might help but I'm not able to track down that URL. Any help, I need to add this back so I can install the Support Library.

[image: The package used to be listed here]
<sub>Forgive my drawing</sub>

I'm on Mac OSX El Capitan (10.11.5)

Answer (score 1):

This is the URL for Android Support Library | rev 23.2.1
http://dl.google.com/android/repository/support_r23.2.1.zip

Additional SDK tools:
https://afterroot.wordpress.com/2016/01/01/android-sdk-extras-package-direct-links/

Comment: Thanks Nir. But I meant to point to the Android Support Library. Which is missing in the screenshot because that's what I deleted.

Comment: @RobinMaben - changed the url, this is what you're looking for?